# API call with for-loop in Angular

Tags: angular, api, for-loop

I have an API get call that I want to loop several times depending on the length of the mockInput.json file.

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

const localMockInput = 'assets/mock-input.json';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(environment.api.username+':'+environment.api.password)
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fetchRealData(_pid: any, _extUserId: any){
    return this.http.get('XXXXX/XXXXX?product='+_pid+'&externalUserId='+_extUserId, httpOptions);
  }

  collectMockRounds(){
   return this.http.get(localMockInput)
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  realData: any = [];
  mockInput: any = [];
  constructor(private api: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.doArray();
  }

  collectMockInput(){
    this.api.collectMockRounds()
    .subscribe(data => {
      for (const e of (data as any)) {
        this.mockInput.push({
          pId: e.PID,
          extUserId: e.extUserID,
        });
      }
      // console.log('Mock Input Successfully Collected:');
      // console.log(this.mockInput);
    });
  }

  doArray(){
    this.collectMockInput();
    for(let i = 0; i < this.mockInput.length; i++){
      console.log(this.mockInput.length)
      this.api.fetchRealData(this.mockInput[i].pId, this.mockInput[i].extUserId)
      .subscribe(data => {
        for (const d of (data as any)) {
          this.realData.push({
            x: d.x,
            y: d.y,
          });
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error.error.errorMessage);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

So when I've fetched the mockdata and its length, I want to loop it with my API call. It seems like I'm doing something wrong here; I do not receive any errors or even the console.log within the loop: `console.log(this.mockInput.length)`.

Any advice or hints would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The `subscribe` is asynchronous so it happens at a later point in time. I will have an answer for you shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs'
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'
....
doArray() {
  this.api.collectMockRounds().pipe(
    // this is an array so it should work
    tap(data => console.log(data)), // can you see what the log is here, make sure data is an array...
    // switch to a new observable
    switchMap(data => {
     console.log(data); // make sure this is an array 
     return combineLatest(
      // combine all of the requests
      ...data.map(input => this.api.fetchRealData(input.PID, input.extUserID)),
    })),
  ).subscribe(data => {
      for (const d of (data as any)) {
          this.realData.push({
            x: d.x,
            y: d.y,
          });
        }
}, error => {
   // handle error
 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply! I tried the following code example above but it seems like I've issues with .map. I receive the following error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.

"typescript": "~3.5.3"
"rxjs": "~6.4.0",
Angular 8
I tried to install rxjs-compat but to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's the array `map` on `...data.map` where `data` is an object and not an array. I added a `tap` to see the log, can you tell me what it logs? Is it an array or object? And if it is an object, can you show me the object?

Comment: Hi AliF50, thank you for your dedication to help me with this; the tap gave me back the entire mock-input.json array; which contains 3 objects: https://i.imgur.com/pEsVHx7.png. Cheers

Comment: So it is an array? And you're unblocked/figured it out?

Comment: It is indeed an array; however, I've not figured out yet fully; I receive: x: undefined in the log output and I still receive: ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(116,17): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'. in the CLI.

Comment: Oddly sometimes I also receive in the console.log: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Comment: I added another `console.log` inside of the `switchMap`, can you make sure that is an array as well?

Comment: I believe it doesn't work to it in that way, sorry the code starting to make me dizzy, I copied the exact code above and received: ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:144:7 - error TS1135: Argument expression expected.

144       })),
          ~
src/app/app.component.ts:145:5 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

145     ).subscribe(data => {
        ~
src/app/app.component.ts:145:6 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

145     ).subscribe(data => {
         ~

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209162/discussion-between-svante-and-alif50).